¿Alguna implementación de map en javascript que compare las claves por sus propiedades?
Tengo un array de objetos todos identicos en estructura y necesito hacer una especie de resumen. Los objetos son de una forma análoga a la siguiente, existen una serie de datos de tipo string y un valor de tipo number:
let elemento = {
    codigoProducto: 'AS769800',
    centroLogistico: 'Abasto',
    tipo: 'residual',
    cantidad: 7
}

Supongamos que en mi array se repiten elementos con identicas propiedades codigoProducto, centroLogistico y tipo, y quiero saber cual es la suma de cantidades para cada combinación.
En defefinitiva necesito un mapa cuyos valores sean de tipo number (la suma de todas las cantidades) y que las claves sean de un tipo que tenga las primeras tres propiedades, en este ejmplo codigoProducto, centroLogistico y tipo.
En un lenguaje mas amigable hacer esto me resulta muy sencillo, por ejemplo en java sería:
// creo un record para mis claves y elementos
public record Clave(String codigoProducto, String centroLogistico, String tipo) { }
public record Elemento(String codigoProducto, String centroLogistico, String tipo, Integer cantidad) { }

List<Elemento> lista = // inicializo mi lista desde alguna base de datos

// recorro mi lista con un stream y combino las claves

Map<Clave, Integer> map = lista.stream().map(elemento -> Map.entry(new 
                  Clave(elemento.codigoproducto(), elemento.centroLogistico(), elemento.tipo()), 
                  elemento.cantidad()))
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                  (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2), HashMap::new));


Bueno esto en js no es posible porque la implementación por defecto de Map es un mapa que compara las claves por referencia, no hay contratos de hashCode y equals o sobreescritura de operadores en js. ¿Existe una forma de resolver este problema, algun módulo que pueda importar con npm que provea estructuras de datos similares a un hashmap o un treemap?

Saludos. Da un vistazo a lodash; acorde a los que mencionas revisa https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

Hola, te dejé una respuesta. Disculpa la demora, pero estaba viendo al Temach en vivo. Yo te sugeriría probar [tag:typescript] que aunque haces mucho más código te será más natural viniendo de backend. intenta a futuro agregarle el formato de salida deseado a tu [mcve]

Hola Miguel, en JS podes crear objetos y utilizarlos como pseudo "arreglo asociativo". Ahora mi pregunta es ¿como quisieras manipular los datos?. Sería bueno que agregaras mas detalles sobre este tema.

@Marcos estaría bien que armaras una respuesta con base en eso, entiendo que los arreglos con índices nombrados son en realidad objetos "arreglos asociativos" y no arreglos (osea no tienen el prototipo de arreglo sino de Object -eso creo-), por lo que algunos de los métodos y propiedades de estos pseudo arreglos ("arreglos asociativos") funcionarán erráticamente

@RuslanLópez, tal cual lo señalas, en JS los objetos no son arreglos por lo que su prototipo carece de los métodos tradicionales para estos últimos. Eso no quita que se puedan usar como "arreglos asociativos". Ej: Dado un objeto podes obtener que propiedades y cuantas son, lo valores, agrupar, etc. Es cuestión de saber que se quiere obtener para encontrarle la vuelta.

No necesitas ninguna implementación especial, ya que Map fue agregado al estandar ECMA-262 en la quita edición y te soporta cualquier tipo de dato como clave o como valor.
demostración


let lista = [{
  codigoProducto: 'AS769800',
  centroLogistico: 'Abasto',
  tipo: 'residual',
  cantidad: 7
}, {
  codigoProducto: 'AS769801',
  centroLogistico: 'Abasto1',
  tipo: 'residual1',
  cantidad: 2
}, {
  codigoProducto: 'AS769800',
  centroLogistico: 'Abasto2',
  tipo: 'residual',
  cantidad: 6
}, {
  codigoProducto: 'AS769802',
  centroLogistico: 'Abasto',
  tipo: 'residual1',
  cantidad: 17
}, {
  codigoProducto: 'AS769801',
  centroLogistico: 'Abasto1',
  tipo: 'residual1',
  cantidad: 1
}];


let mapa = lista.reduce((acumulador, elemento) => acumulador.set({
  "codigoProducto": elemento.codigoProducto,
  "centroLogistico": elemento.centroLogistico,
  "tipo": elemento.tipo
}, elemento.cantidad), new Map());

console.log('Entradas del mapa:', [...mapa.entries()]);

//console.log([...mapa.keys()]);

//console.log([...mapa.values()]);

let agrupado = Object.groupBy(mapa.entries(), (value) => value[0].codigoProducto)

console.log('Objeto agrupado:\n', agrupado)



sé que le debe parecer magia por la ausencia de tipos y antes de que me regañen o me bajen puntos le haré un disclaimer antes de la explicación.
ADVERTENCIA: El diseño de los mapas está recomendado tener la clave del tipo de dato más pequeño posible para que al calcular el hash y realizar la búsqueda de elementos sea más eficiente
Explicación del código de la demostración
en el caso de JavaScript el método Map.set nos regresa una referencia al mapa modificado con la nueva entrada y recibe dos parámetros, la clave y el valor respectivamente.
los objetos en javascript se representan mediante la notación json, y si bien no son instancias de objetos como tal es común verlas que se usen como si fueran Records, es decir solo contenedores de datos sin métodos, por lo que no necesitaremos ni siquiera convertirlos a objeto (Eso normalmente se haría con JSON.parse()).
En la notación JSON siempre deberemos de tener clave : valor y la clave siempre debe de ir con comillas dobles1.
Una observación que debes de notar es que normalmente los mapas no se pueden imprimir en consola, de allí que haya usado destructuración para imprimir el mapa.
Hasta allí llevamos lo suficiente para crear el mapa del tipo que quieres (lo cual como te imaginarás pienso que es una barbaridad y hasta aquí me hace sentido).
Como el último paso es agrupar allí hay diferentes forms de hacerlo, una muy reciente de este año 2024 es usar Object.groupBy que opera sobre un Iterable, como lo es nuestro método keys, entries o values.
el segundo parámetro de groupBy es un callback, es decir, lo que en Java sería una Function o cualquiera de sus subclases que sería la función que nos permitiría obtener la clave de agrupación.
Como verás el resultado es un objeto, yo usé el campo codigoProducto para que tus búsquedas dentro del objeto sean eficientes y tengan más sentido que usar el objeto complejo para agrupar quedándote un objeto
{
  "AS769800": [
    [
      {
        "codigoProducto": "AS769800",
        "centroLogistico": "Abasto",
        "tipo": "residual"
      },
      7
    ],
    [
      {
        "codigoProducto": "AS769800",
        "centroLogistico": "Abasto2",
        "tipo": "residual"
      },
      6
    ]
  ],
  "AS769801": [
    [
      {
        "codigoProducto": "AS769801",
        "centroLogistico": "Abasto1",
        "tipo": "residual1"
      },
      2
    ],
    [
      {
        "codigoProducto": "AS769801",
        "centroLogistico": "Abasto1",
        "tipo": "residual1"
      },
      1
    ]
  ],
  "AS769802": [
    [
      {
        "codigoProducto": "AS769802",
        "centroLogistico": "Abasto",
        "tipo": "residual1"
      },
      17
    ]
  ]
}

que como verás contiene cada código de producto como nombre de cada campo y como valor un arreglo con entradas clave valor, donde la clave es tu sección del objeto y tu valor es el valor del campo cantidad.
Como para obtener una respuesta más adecuada necesito más información en la pregunta (por ejemplo como quieres que sea tu objeto de salida), hasta aquí te dejo estos fragmentos esperando que te sean de utilidad
Notas
1 Hay una especificación llamada JSON5 que permite comillas simples, pero ya que maneja Java digamos que JSON estándard se utiliza para serialzair/deserialziar con cualquier librería y JSON5 solo la he visto con gson.

Perfecto, es lo que necesitaba. perdon por ser poco claro en el resultado que quería.

Lo que tú quieres es el típico "agrupar y sumar" que se realiza muy comúnmente en SQL.
Javascript está muy al debe de funciones utilitarias, no obstante, tiene lo básico para crear nuestras propias funciones.
1.- Suma
Partamos por lo más fácil, que es crear una función que permita sumar un Array, lo cual se puede lograr simplemente utilizando un reduce
Demo:


Array.prototype.Sum = function (exp = null) {
    if (exp == null)
        return this.reduce((a, i) => a += i, 0);
    else if (exp instanceof Function)
        return this.reduce((a, i) => a += exp(i), 0);
    else
        return this.reduce(a => a += exp, 0);
}

const Array1 = [1,3,4,5]; // array de números
console.log(Array1.Sum()); 

const Array2 = [ {cantidad:1},{cantidad:4} ]; //array de objetos
console.log(Array2.Sum(x=>x.cantidad)); 

const Array3 = [ "a","bb","ccc" ]; //array de string
console.log(Array3.Sum(x=>x.length));  //sumar la cantidad de letras



2.- Agrupar
Antiguamente esto también se podía realizar con un reduce, pero desde hace un tiempo que existe el groupBy nativo.
Lamentablemente tiene algunos problemas:

Es una función estática de Object y se usa: Object.groupBy(iterable, callbackFn), esta forma es incómoda para encadenar funciones
Retorna un objeto a modo de diccionario, donde cada propiedad es la clave (el factor de agrupación) y su valor es un array de los elementos agrupados. Me hubiese gustado que retornara un arrays de arrays, pero supongo que habrá casos de usos que requieren un diccionario
El problema de la clave, esto es lo que describes en tu pregunta y es el problema principal en tu caso. Cuando quieres agrupar por una sola propiedad (del tipo primitivo) no hay problema, pero cuando quieres agrupar por múltiples propiedades comienza el lio, porque lo lógico sería agrupar por un objeto, pero como tu bien señalaste los objetos se comparan por referencia y no hay modo sencillo de hacerlo por valor

Hay 2 formas clasicas de abordades este problema:

Usar JSON.stringify y comparar cadenas
Usar un algoritmo de búsqueda en profundidad y comparar propiedad a propiedad.

La primera forma es simple, pero tiene teóricamente problemas de performance, aunque en mi experiencia con varios miles de datos no es nada preocupante. La segunda forma tiene el problema de ser un algoritmo complejo especialmente cuando se consideran objetos con referencias circulares.
No obstante todo lo anterior, pienso que para tu caso particular, al ser un objeto bastante simple yo utilizaría una tercera forma, que consiste simplemente en crear una clave concatenando los valores de las propiedades
Este objeto
{
    codigoProducto: 'AS769800',
    centroLogistico: 'Abasto',
    tipo: 'residual',
    cantidad: 7
}

Tendrá la clave: "AS769800|Abasto|residual
Con esto podemos crear una función GroupBy basandonos en la nativa, pero mejorándola para este caso.
Array.prototype.GroupBy = function(fn){
  return Object.values(Object.groupBy(this, a => {
      const x = fn(a);
      if(Array.isArray(x)){
        return x.join("|");
      }
      return x;
  }));
}

Ya con nuestras funciones utilitarias, podemos hacer:
const result = elementos
               .GroupBy(a=>[a.codigoProducto,a.centroLogistico,a.tipo])
               .map(a=> ( {...a[0], cantidad: a.Sum(v=>v.cantidad)}));

Demo:


const elementos = [{
    codigoProducto: 'AS769800',
    centroLogistico: 'Abasto',
    tipo: 'residual',
    cantidad: 7
},{
    codigoProducto: 'AS769800',
    centroLogistico: 'Abasto',
    tipo: 'residual',
    cantidad: 7
},{
    codigoProducto: 'AAAAAAA',
    centroLogistico: 'Abasto',
    tipo: 'residual',
    cantidad: 7
}];



Array.prototype.GroupBy = function(fn){
  return Object.values(Object.groupBy(this, a => {
      const x = fn(a);
      if(Array.isArray(x)){
        return x.join("|");
      }
      return x;
  }));
}
Array.prototype.Sum = function (exp = null) {
    if (exp == null)
        return this.reduce((a, i) => a += i, 0);
    else if (exp instanceof Function)
        return this.reduce((a, i) => a += exp(i), 0);
    else
        return this.reduce(a => a += exp, 0);
}


const result = elementos
               .GroupBy(a=>[a.codigoProducto,a.centroLogistico,a.tipo] )
               .map(a=> ( {...a[0], cantidad: a.Sum(v=>v.cantidad)}));

console.log(result);



